# Parse and search JSON file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, search

I’m trying to write some code to parse and search a JSON file for an industry. The code will be added to an autocomplete script and return items they were found (not relevant to to this question). I have the following JSON file:

```
{
  "sectors": [
    {
      "title": "Business, Finance & Technology",
      "subsectors": [
        {
          "title": "Finance and insurance",
          "industries": [
            {
              "name": "Retail banking",
              "name": "Insurance",
              "name": "Investment banking"
            }
          ],
          "title": "Business Services",
          "industries": [
            {
              "name": "Accounting & Audit",
              "name": "Recruitment",
              "name": "Legal services"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "title": "Life & Consumer",
      "subsectors": [
        {
          "title": "Life Sciences",
          "industries": [
            {
              "name": "Biotechnology",
              "name": "Pharmaceutical",
              "name": "Medical supplies"
            }
          ],
          "title": "Healthcare",
          "industries": [
            {
              "name": "Surgery",
              "name": "Medicine",
              "name": "Nursery"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this code:

```
var q = 'Insurance';
$.getJSON('models/industries.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    if (item.sectors.subsectors.industries.search(new RegExp(q, "i")) != -1) {
      $('<li />').html(item.name).appendTo('body');
    }
  });
});
```

However, it’s not working.

I tried different variations:

```
if (item.name.search(new RegExp(q, "i")) != -1) {
```

This one throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'search' of undefined`

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @Arun P Johny below, I fixed the issues. There were issues with my JSON file: curly braces `{}` were needed for each `industry`, `subsector`, and `sector`. And I needed to iterate over each `subsector` and `sector`:

```
var q = 'Insurance',
    regex = new RegExp(q, "i");
$.getJSON('models/industries.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data.sectors, function (i, sector) {
        $.each(sector.subsectors, function (i, subsector) {
            $.each(subsector.industries, function (i, industry) {
                if (industry.name.search(regex) != -1) {
                    $('<li />').html(industry.name).appendTo('body');
                }
            })
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I see you're attempting to use regex.  Try http://json.spiritway.co and see if this better matches your needs since the iterative approach is cumbersome and 5x slower than the string-based search/JSON rebuild the library I've linked runs with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over `sectors`, `subsectors` and `industries` arrays

```
var q = 'Insurance',
    regex = new RegExp(q, "i");
$.getJSON('models/industries.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data.sectors, function (i, sector) {
        $.each(sector.subsectors, function (i, subsector) {
            $.each(subsector.industries, function (i, industry) {
                if (industry.name.search(regex) != -1) {
                    $('<li />').html(industry.name).appendTo('body');
                }
            })
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I’m still getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'search'`

Comment: @Alex try `industry.name.search(regex)`

Comment: The error is gone but the result is not appended. The code inside `if` is not being executed.

Comment: For some reason `industry.name` brings up `Nursery` which is the last element.

Comment: @Alex you have another problem `{
    "name": "Biotechnology",
    "name": "Pharmaceutical",
    "name": "Medical supplies"
}` is invalid it should be `[{
    "name": "Biotechnology"
}, {
    "name": "Pharmaceutical"
}, {
    "name": "Medical supplies"
}]`

Comment: It is like you wrote. The `[]` are part of the `"industries": [` which is above that line.

Comment: @Alex each `"name": "Biotechnology"` should be like `{"name": "Biotechnology"}`

Comment: Thanks, Arun. Sorry for not catching it earlier. JSON newbie…

Comment: @Alex when I initially saw that in your code I thought it was a copy paste mistake that is why I didn't mention it

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the `sectors` array, so the `each` code should be:

```
$.each(data.sectors, function(i, item) {
    if (item.subsectors.industries.search(new RegExp(q, "i")) != -1) {
        $('<li />').html(item.name).appendTo('body');
    }
});
```

Also, your `item.name` value will be undefined as you need to access `item.subsectors[0].industries[0].name`. The properties with `[0]` after them are arrays, which you will need to loop over if you need to retrieve all values from them. `[0]` will just get you the first value.